# Declarar Set<double> - JAVA

Tags: java

Queria saber como declarar um conjunto com tipo genérico que não seja uma classe. Exemplo: `Set<double>`.

Todos os exemplos que eu vi o conjunto é de uma classe.

Estou começando a ver agora a ver conjuntos. Preciso fazer um `Set` que tenha 20 números aleatórios e tire uma média.

Vou ter que criar uma classe com atributo `double` pra fazer isso? Ou tem outra maneira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os conjuntos, que implementam a interface `Collection` do `Java`, como `ArrayList, LinkedList, HashSet, etc...` não aceitam tipos primitivos.

Mas nada impede você de declarar um `Set<Double> seuSet` e depois fazer `seuSet.add(2.33)`, um double primitivo. O Java utiliza os **Wrappers** ou **invólucros** quando isso acontece.

Todo tipo primitivo no java tem um `Wrapper` correspondente:

```
int => Integer
long => Long
float => Float
double => Double
... assim por diante...
```

Então quando você tenta adicionar um double primitivo ao array fazendo assim `seuSet.add(2.33)` , na verdade o Java executa o seguinte: `seuSet.add(new Double(2.33))`

E, para o que você está querendo, que é tirar uma média dos números, não vejo problema em fazer dessa maneira.

Answer (score 2):

De fato, você não pode usar tipos primitivos nas `Collections` do Java.

Se quer trabalhar com `double` e `Set`, para o seu caso, as alternativas são:

- Usar alguma biblioteca que forneça collections
  implementada com tipos primitivos, como [Trove](http://java-performance.info/primitive-types-collections-trove-library/) ou [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html);
- Fazer sua própria implementação :);
- Usar `Set<Double>` mesmo, se o `double` primitivo não for uma obrigatoriedade;